# Is there a way to delete characters after @ in an email address?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to delete characters after "@" in an email address using python. I found some tips online but it didn't provide the exact solution I am looking for.

The whole email address I'm working on is coming from a parameter value.

```
paramater = [0]  #contains the email address i.e. testing@email.com
mainStr = parameter [0]
newstring = mainStr.replace('@' , ' ')
```

Obviously, the above code is not providing me with result I am expecting which is to delete all strings after @.

Comment: I learned a tip a while back. If you are printing an array to the console, and you want to delete unnecessary values, then don't delete them, just don't print them. You don't have to delete the characters after `@`, just don't print them.

Answer (score 2):

```
in = 'test@gmail.com'
out = s.split('@')[0]
```

or

```
out = ''.join(re.findall('(.*)@',s))
```

Comment: You can do `s.split('@', 1)[0]`, it _would_ be even faster.

Comment: this is true..but since OP is about email addresses, there will only be one split

Comment: In fact `.split(..., 1)` was slower ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: >>> timeit('"test@gmail.com".split("@", 1)[0]')
0.20608205100143095
>>> timeit('"test@gmail.com".split("@")[0]')
0.20366473000467522

Comment: XD weird .. thought you wouldve been right

Comment: Me too :D, maybe an obscure optimization is taking place

Answer (score 1):

With regex

```
import re
re.sub(r'@.*', '', 'test@email.com')
```

Comment: was hoping someone would bust out the regex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code.
But, I write code by my way.

```
s = test@email.com
end = s.find('@')
s[:end]
```

Comment: Rephrase your answer to capture what you mean,  s = 'test@email.com' and there should be a print statement at the end of your code block.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a part of account? ( for example " testing" in "testing@baba.net")

Then

```
exampleString = "testing@baba.net"
indexOfAt = exampleString.find("@") # get index of @
print (indexOfAt)
accountPart = exampleString[:indexOfAt]
print (accountPart)
```

the result is as follows

```
7
testing
```

Comment: exact copy of other solution